# Boost Video Performance

Tags: video, intel

I am having Broxton board. If I install Windows-10 onto it and play Ultra-HD video then it plays very smoothly. But If I install Ubuntu-16.10 onto the same hardware then the performance of same video is comparatively poor.

Is there any way to boost up video performance ? *(Or is there any way to find out hardware capability to play at what extent it can play video smoothly ?)*

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not install and enable the accelerated video playback libraries by default.
Install `i965-va-driver` (and optionally `vainfo` for testing).

For gstreamer based players (such as totem) `gstreamer0.10-vaapi` is needed as well

For vlc, the acceleration must be enabled in the settings.